# Salesforce is adding a sandbox name at the end of contact's emails

Tags: email, contact, sandbox, salesfoce

For some reason, Salesforce is adding a sandbox name at the end of all contact's email address'. So for example if my contact's email is anita@gmail.com and it ends with anita@gmail.com.full. Any ideas why it happens?

Comment: I've never seen this on contacts, only on users.  Are you sure it's on contact?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's on contact.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behaviour to ensure that no unwanted emails actually reach the person. You may have automation in your org that spams the recipients, you probably don't want this to happen uncontrolled.
So by invalidating email addresses (and making sure you can find out what is going wrong) Salesforce prevents you from automatically and involuntarily sending out emails.

Comment: Is there a way to disable it (at least for a particular period of time) ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. If I need to have valid addresses in a sandbox, I retrieve the records with dataloader, search & replace the name of the sandbox with nothing, and save the data with data loader again. Crude, but works.

Comment: Tried with your solution but it doesn't work - after I update data with a Data Loader, there's still the name of the sandbox visible.

Comment: Hi Kitka92, maybe we have a miscommunication. You can update the email address, not the username. The username is usually globally unique. If you have x@y.com on production and x@y.com.sandbox on your sandbox, renaming the sandbox user would create 2 users with the same user name.